# If $A$,$B$ and $C$ are two sets then $A\cup ( B\cap C)=(A\cup B)\cap(A\cup C)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I was reading a book relating set theory. I was studying about the various properties of sets and their operations  . One such properties  describe : If $A$,$B$ and $C$ are two sets then $A\cup ( B\cap  C)=(A\cup B)\cap(A\cup C)$ .

My approach is quite lengthy and it's a quite straightforward approach :

> I tried to prove $$(A\cup B)\cap (A\cup C)\subset A\cup( B\cap C)$$
> and $$A\cup( B\cap C)\subset (A\cup B)\cap (A\cup C)$$ such that  $$(A\cup B)\cap (A\cup C)=A\cup( B\cap C)$$. So for $$A\cup( B\cap C)\subset (A\cup B)\cap (A\cup C)$$ we start by $x\in A\cup( B\cap C)$. Thus, $x\in A$ or $x\in B\cap C$ which means $x\in A$ or ($x\in B$ and $x\in C)$. We can write , $(x\in A $ and $x\in B)$ or $(x\in A $ and $x\in C)$ which means $x\in (A\cup B)\cap (A\cup C)$. Similarly, we can prove the other way and thus we will have an equality.

Now, in this proof when I wrote the statements " $x\in A$ or ($x\in B$ and $x\in C)$" followed by " $(x\in A $ and $x\in B)$ or $(x\in A $ and $x\in C)$" , I wrote it only because I found the two statements to be logically equivalent . However, I do want to know if there are some properties of "or" and "and" in mathematics and where and how can we use them? I am not quite getting it .

Answer (score 1):

"Or" and "and" have their usual everyday English meanings in mathematics as long as you think of "or" as "and/or", not "or but not both".

Comment: So which means I can write those statements equivalently only because I found them to be logically equivalent , right? Can you please explain what do u mean by thinking " or"  as "and/or" ? Do u mean thinking "or" as a word which has an equivalent meaning with "or" and "and" in English ?

Comment: In English if you say "would you like cake or ice cream for dessert?" the unspoken idea is that it's one or the other but not both. In mathematics the person making the offer would allow "both" as an answer.

Comment: I do understand your idea ...Thank you so much for that...but the thing is can I write those statements mentioned in the original post as a point from sheer logic? One more thing , "or" and "and" in mathematics are used in general sense , right? Thirdly, there is no properties associated with "and" and "or" , right? If it is not the case , then please point out the properties ? Thank you .....

Comment: I can't help you more than I already have, so no more questions please. In this argument all that matters is that your words make sense in English. There is no "sheer logic" or any special mathematical use of "and" and "or" here.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I do get it...I asked it only because in some books it's written sometimes "or is distributive over and " (or maybe "and is distributive over or", I don't quite remember it)  and hence the question ......but thanks a lot!